# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame rename index problems

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, rename

In an existing table I got some summary  by

```
df.groupby('bin_fare')['fare'].agg(['count', 'sum', 'mean'])
```

The result is table above. bin_fare name of Indexes

bin_fare    count    sum    mean

**1**    491    3717.1413   7.570553

**2**    474    9000.3078   18.987991

**3**    259    14565.0003  14565.0003

**4**    84     16268.0375  16268.0375

I tried to rename indexes by adding this code

```
fare_rate_names = ['cheapest','avarage','above average','expensive']
df.groupby('bin_fare')['fare'].agg(['count','sum','mean']).rename(index=pd.Series(data=fare_rate_names))
```

But it renames only first 3 row !

bin_fare    count    sum    mean

**avarage**    491    3717.1413   7.570553

**above average**    474    9000.3078   18.987991

**expensive**    259    14565.0003  14565.0003

**4**    84     16268.0375  16268.0375

How to fix it? Not adding element at the beginning of **fare_rate_names**

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a new index:

```
df.index = pd.Series(fare_rate_names)
```

Or, the more pythonic ("pandastic"?):

```
df.set_index(pd.Series(fare_rate_names), inplace=True)
```

Also, you could create a dummy name for the 0th index:

```
fare_rate_names = ['foo', 'cheapest','avarage','above average','expensive']
df.groupby('bin_fare')['fare'].agg(['count','sum','mean']).rename(index=pd.Series(data=fare_rate_names))
```